# UISplitViewController and Modal view controller presentation issues

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I am having troubles with an application where I have a split view controller and would like to display a modal view controller over the top.

To test this, I have created a basic project which mimics the structure of my application. I have uploaded this to Github for anyone to download: https://github.com/CaptainRedmuff/SplitViewDemo

There are two main issues which I will detail below:

**Issue 1**:

When presenting the modal view controller in portrait orientation with the master view controller visible (as a popover I believe), the modal view controller is displayed underneath the master view controller. Any attempts to interact with the model view controller cause the app to crash.

**Issue 2**:

When presenting the modal view controller from the tab bar controller (in the master view controller), the modal view controller is automatically dismissed when the device is rotated to landscape orientation as the master view controller is removed from the hierarchy.

One possible fix I have found is to conform to the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` method `- (BOOL)splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation:` and return `NO` to force the master view controller to always be visible. This is not the behaviour that I want however so this is not a viable fix.

Considering that there is no way to programatically display or dismiss the master view controller, I am at a loss for alternative methods to present a view controller modally over the top of the entire split view controller.

Answer (score -1):

Before presenting modal VC you must dismiss popover like:

```
[self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
```

The issue occurred probably because `UIPopoverController` is added to the window instead of `UISplitViewController`.